# Android srec_jni

Tags: android, c++, speech-recognition, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am developing application for google now, I got the code for Speech Recognition Engine but it looks there are lot of header files related to it. I would like to know where I can get the srec_jni complete source code that includes the related header files also, every I am getting the basic files of srec_jni not all the related header files.